# Get HTML <input> value in Java

Tags: javascript, java, html

I've searched arround on Google but couldn't find a clear answer on my question. The idea of what I want to do is quite simple:

There's a site called "glws.org" with a bunch of `<div>`'s and `<input>`'s on the page. You can add strings to the URL (example: https://glws.org/#S76561198105687636A2280482163D16883436630920468625) and for different strings after the # in the URL, different values are put into the `<input>`'s. The site reads the string after the # and has a script that converts it into values and puts the values in read-only `<input>`'s. Because they are `<input>`'s and not `<p>`'s for example, I can't just read them by printing out the HTML code.

Is there a way to retrieve the value in the input fields through a Java program? I've tried to read the source code of the page with Sockets but that obviously just prints the `<input>` tags without the value because it's not like a `<p>` or something.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your question appears to be missing words; please read it over and edit it for clarity.

Comment: next time use this thingy around your code lol `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Selenium` web driver to do browser actions on the website programatically and wait till some elements appear on the page.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted